# Assistant not using Action on Google when command is long

Tags: actions-on-google

If I say

```
ask AutoVoice to expense $25 for test category test
```

or any command with 7 words or more, Google Assistant will not call my service but will instead do a normal search.

If I say something shorter like

```
ask Autovoice to say hello there
```

It'll call my Action on Google.

I expected the assistant to call my action when either a short or long command is used.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. I'd start by looking here https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity to see what the Assistant thinks you said. I'm not sure about this but I seem to recall that invocation names need to be two words long. If your invocation name is properly recognized and your Action is not invoked I'd open a support ticket. My Action was tripped up by a bug in the 'cloud' somewhere which cause commands to my action to be served by a web or YouTube search rather my Action for roughly 3 months.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Google Assistant did indeed hear me correctly. I've been having other bugs too where the full command isn't sent to my action. For example, if I say "ask autovoice to turn lights on" I only get "turn lights" and not the "on" part. Where would you open a ticket? I thought this was the official public way to report errors nowadays?

Comment: Here you go: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Comment: Yes, I contacted them via that form before. Have yet to get an answer on this. Thanks again.

Comment: Does it work if you break it into two commands, ie. "Talk to auto voice" and "expense $25..."

Comment: Yes, that works correctly.